# Blog not responding to underlying list changes

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, blog

I have a blog that uses an underlying list (SharePoint 2010). 
I have changed the view so that any blog post in the Category "Test Post" will not appear in this list (be hidden)(it works!). However, when I return to the blog the posts are still there (not hidden). How can I have the blog become "responsive" to any changes I make to the underlying list.

I was thinking that if the post is hidden in the list it should be hidden in the blog.
Has anyone else had this issue? How can I get the blog to replicate the properties of the list?

Thank you.

Comment: did you publish the changes?

Comment: yes I have pubished changes..

Comment: Can you be specific on how you are hiding the blog post?

Comment: Editing the view:
(List settings - Manage posts)
Editing the filter so that:
Show items when column [Category] is not equal to "Test Post"
How can I have this apply to the actual blog? Thank you

Comment: Views are specific to the webpart or page that shows the content. That does not reflect the rest of the webparts that show the underlying content. You need to edit the webpart, or change the view of the webpart that is listing the blog posts.

Comment: Thank you! How can I modify the view/webpart of the actual blog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views are specific to the webpart or page that shows the content. That does not reflect the rest of the webparts that show the underlying content. You need to edit the webpart, or change the view of the webpart that is listing the blog posts.

Each page the content is on could potentially have their own view unless you tie it all to one named view. Just edit the page wherever you see blog posts and you can edit the webpart or change the view.